# GridTemplateColumn databinding to complex properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, syncfusion, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have 3 model classes as follows (Vegetable, Fruit and ItemInBasket):

```
public class Vegetable
    {
        string name;
        public string Name
        {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }


    public Vegetable(string _Name)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
    }
}

public class Fruit
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }


    public Fruit(string _Name)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
    }
}

public class ItemInBasket
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    object fruitorvegetable;
    public object FruitOrVegetable
    {
        get { return fruitorvegetable; }
        set { fruitorvegetable = value; }
    }

    int quantity;
    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set { quantity = value; }
    }

    public ItemInBasket(string _Name, object _FruitOrVegetable, int _Quantity)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
        this.FruitOrVegetable = _FruitOrVegetable;
        this.quantity = _Quantity;
    }
}
```

My ViewModel is:

```
public class ViewModel
    {
    private ObservableCollection<object> _availableItems;
    public ObservableCollection<object> AvailableItems
    {
        get { return _availableItems; }
        set { _availableItems = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ItemInBasket> _itemsInBasket;
    public ObservableCollection<ItemInBasket> ItemsInBasket
    {
        get { return _itemsInBasket; }
        set { _itemsInBasket = value; }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _availableItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        _itemsInBasket = new ObservableCollection<ItemInBasket>();
        this.GenerateAvailableItems();
        this.GenerateItemsInBasket();
    }

    private void GenerateAvailableItems()
    {
        _availableItems.Add(new Vegetable("Broccoli"));         // index 0
        _availableItems.Add(new Vegetable("Kale"));             // index 1
        _availableItems.Add(new Vegetable("Spinach"));          // index 2
        _availableItems.Add(new Vegetable("Carrots"));          // index 3
        _availableItems.Add(new Vegetable("Garlic"));           // index 4

        _availableItems.Add(new Fruit("Apple"));                // index 5
        _availableItems.Add(new Fruit("Orange"));               // index 6
        _availableItems.Add(new Fruit("Pear"));                 // index 7
        _availableItems.Add(new Fruit("Cherry"));               // index 8
        _availableItems.Add(new Fruit("Grape"));                // index 9
    }

    private void GenerateItemsInBasket()
    {
        _itemsInBasket.Add(new ItemInBasket("Apples",_availableItems[5],3));
        _itemsInBasket.Add(new ItemInBasket("Kale", _availableItems[1], 10));
        _itemsInBasket.Add(new ItemInBasket("Grape", _availableItems[9], 2));
        _itemsInBasket.Add(new ItemInBasket("Carrots", _availableItems[3], 1));
    }
}
```

I am trying to be able to modify the FruitOrVegetable inside of each ItemInBasket displayed in the datagrid but I have an issue with the data binding. I am using Syncfusion datagrid but I think it shouldnt affect anything.

```
    <syncfusion:SfDataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single"
                    AllowEditing="True" AllowDeleting="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsInBasket,Source={StaticResource viewModel}}">
        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>

            <syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn MappingName="FruitOrVegetable" HeaderText="Order">
                <syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn.EditTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  SelectedValuePath="Name"
                                  Text="{Binding FruitOrVegetable.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableItems, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn.EditTemplate>
                <syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn>

            <syncfusion:GridNumericColumn HeaderText="Quantity" MappingName ="Quantity"/>

        </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
    </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement to display the modified value of the FruitOrVegetable in SfDataGrid can be achieved by binding the SelectedValue property of ComboBox. Please refer to the below code snippet,

```
                        <ComboBox IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  SelectedValuePath="Name"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding Name}"
                                  Text="{Binding FruitOrVegetable.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableItems, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where what we call an "interface" comes in handy. This gives you the surety that the properties are indeed present on this object. Consider it a contract between the class and interface to always include some properties.
You can learn more about it [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-interface)

You can define an interface like this

```
public interface INamedItem
{
    string Name {get;set;}   
}
```

Now instead of the `object` type use this interface(first implement them in your vegetable and fruit class) so that you can easily bind to it(and many other benefits)

```
public class Vegetable : INamedItem
    {
        string name;
        public string Name
        {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }


    public Vegetable(string _Name)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
    }
}

public class Fruit: INamedItem
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }


    public Fruit(string _Name)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
    }
}

public class ItemInBasket
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    INamedItem fruitorvegetable;
    public object FruitOrVegetable
    {
        get { return fruitorvegetable; }
        set { fruitorvegetable = value; }
    }

    int quantity;
    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set { quantity = value; }
    }

    public ItemInBasket(string _Name, INamedItem _FruitOrVegetable, int _Quantity)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
        this.FruitOrVegetable = _FruitOrVegetable;
        this.quantity = _Quantity;
    }
}
```

For your available items it becomes:

```
private ObservableCollection<INamedItem> _availableItems;
    public ObservableCollection<INamedItem> AvailableItems
    {
        get { return _availableItems; }
        set { _availableItems = value; }
    }
```

Now add normally as you have in your code so no more changes to that and check if it works :)

Comment: Thanks for the interface tip. What about the data binding issue? Also I noticed that my ItemInBasket Name field does not change when my FruitOrVegetable changes. The only way around it is I have to add some setting logic in the set portion of the FruitOrVegetable.

Comment: the plot of my answer is that binding fails because "name" doesn't exist on type `object` anyway check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118934/itemsource-binding-on-combobox-inside-a-datagrid try using interface and this solution to see if the issue is resolved

Comment: It doesnt, no change to previous behavior. I think I am not binding properly to the FruitOrVegetable object in that ObservableCollection.

Comment: Selected value path is set to name(of the combobox) while you want to select the object